# Finishing and removing fragment and going back to the MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
Android Studio 3.4
```

I have a simple stock forecast app that uses single activity called ForecastActivity and 3 fragments called `LoadingFragment`, `ForecastFragment`, and `RetryFragment`

The `RetryFragment` will be added first using the following code in the

```
`ForecastActivity`:
 private fun startRetryFragment() {
        fragmentManager?.let {
            val fragmentTransaction = it.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.forecastActivityContainer, RetryFragment(), "RetryFragment")
            fragmentTransaction.commit()
        }
    }
```

I have a button in the `RetryFragment` that will start the `ForecastActivity` again.

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        btnRetry.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(activity, ForecastActivity::class.java))
        }
    }
```

Then the `LoadingFragment` will start using this code in the `ForecastActvity`

```
 private fun startLoadingFragment() {
        fragmentManager?.let {
            val fragmentTransaction = it.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.forecastActivityContainer, LoadingFragment(), "LoadingFragment")
            fragmentTransaction.commit()
        }
    }
```

Then after loading has completed the ForecatActivity will start the `ForecastFragment`

```
private fun startForecastFragment() {
        fragmentManager?.let {
            val fragmentTransaction = it.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.forecastActivityContainer, RetryFragment(), "ForecastFragment")
            fragmentTransaction.commit()
        }
```

In my `ForecastActivity` I am trying to remove the fragments from the backstack, basically, from here I just want to finish the app. However, as I didn't add any to the backstack I don't expect the count to greater than zero. However, I was wondering how can I end the app and prevent the `RetryFragment` displaying again?

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        fragmentManager?.let {
            if(it.backStackEntryCount > 0) {

                it.popBackStackImmediate()
            }
            else {
                super.onBackPressed()
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when I click the back from when I am on the `ForecastFragment` I expect the application to finish. However, the `RetryFragment` is displayed and then I have to click the back button again to end the app.

Is there something wrong doing this in the `RetryFragment`
Basically, I just want to go back to the ForecastActivity from the `RetryFragment` to start again.
`startActivity(Intent(activity, ForecastActivity::class.java))`

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I think your issue is that you're re-launching the `ForecastActivity` again from the `RetryFragment`. If you restructure your code so that the `RetryFragment` can trigger a retry function in `ForecastActivity`, you could just replace the `RetryFragment` with the next appropriate fragment instead of calling `startActivity()` to create a new `ForecastActivity`. TL/DR: Don't call `startActivity()` from `RetryFragment` to start `ForecastActivity`.

Comment: Another option, if you want to keep the `startActivity()` function, is to make the `ForecastActivity` either `singleTop` or `singleTask`. Then you can receive the new `Intent` in `onNewIntent()` on the `Activity` and reload from there.

Comment: @bradford2000 I used your first suggestion. Working now. If you make this an answer I will click as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that you're re-launching the `ForecastActivity` again from the `RetryFragment`. If you restructure your code so that the `RetryFragment` can trigger a retry function in `ForecastActivity`, you could just replace the `RetryFragment` with the next appropriate fragment instead of calling `startActivity()` to create a new `ForecastActivity`.